# Como centralizar imagem ao texto?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de usar a imagem centralizada ao texto, mas só consegui alinhá-la a esquerda ou à direita.

Tem como centralizá-la, fazendo que o texto envolva toda a imagem?

O código que fiz está abaixo:

```
<style>
body{
margin:0 auto;
background:#FFF;
}
div{
margin:0 auto;
height:auto;
width:400px;
background:#CCC;
}
img{
width:100px;
height:auto;
float: right;  /* OU float: left; que alinha a esquerda */
padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div>
Aldous Huxley publicou o seu Brave New World em 1932. George Orwell, que não tinha em grande conta este livro ou o seu autor, publicou 17 anos depois a sua própria distopia, Nineteen Eighty-Four. Entre estas duas datas interpôs-se a Segunda Grande Guerra: não admira que na primeira a técnica básica da opressão do Estado fosse a manipulação genética e que na segunda, depois do descrédito em que o regime nazi lançou o eugenismo, as técnicas principais da opressão sejam a lavagem ao cérebro, a crueldade gratuita e a manipulação da linguagem.
Apesar desta e de outras diferenças, os dois textos foram muitas

<img src="upload/logotipo.png" />

vezes lidos, nas décadas seguintes, como os dois pólos - um hedonista, outro o oposto disto - duma mesma distopia, a que os sinais dos tempos davam e dão plausibilidade. Esta distopia bipolar é identificável em grande parte com a ideia de modernidade; e hoje a invocação da modernidade, sempre na boca dos políticos e dos capitães da indústria, soa aos nossos ouvidos tanto a ameaça como a promessa.
 </div>
 </body>
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção dos amigos.

Comment: Cara, float não é exatamente o melhor jeito para se alinhar não.
Você pode postar o html pra gente dar uma olhada?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que c quer não fei. No caso aí é só colocar um `text-align: center` na `div` e tirar o `float` da imagem.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, e incluir o html completo. Eu quero fazer com que a imagem seja envolvida pelo texto, ou seja a imagem centralizada no meio do texto.

Comment: Você quer uma parte do texto em cima, a imagem embaixo no meio e o resto do texto embaixo da imagem ? Ou você quer texto, imagem, texto, um do lado do outro ?

Comment: Valeu galera, mas descobri onde eu já tinha visto o que eu estou querendo fazer! Foi no Word, nele podemos inserir uma imagem e posiciona-la onde bem queremos dentro do texto, inclusive no centro, com o texto envolvendo toda a imagem. Mas valeu mesmo pela atenção, vou estudar uma forma de como fazer algo parecido. Abraços à todos.

Comment: Relacionada1: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268701/texto-contornando-imagem-div-redonda/268718#268718 Relacionada2: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203108/contornar-imagem-com-texto-em-css/328705#328705

Comment: Veja [esse guia de flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), ou [esse guia em português](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/).

Answer (score 0):

Eu inseri o seguinte código na tag `img` e quase resolveu seu problema, só não ficou muito bem centralizado;

```
...
img {
  width:100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  /* Código para centralizar a imagem */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
...
```

[image: Exemplo de como ficou]

Acredito que com alguns ajustes você consiga chegar no resultado esperado.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode incluir margin:0 auto; no css para a imagem e tirar o float.

```
img{
width:100px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Camarada, tire o float dessa tag `<img>`, e coloque um text-align:center nessa tag `<div>` que comporta o texto e a imagem que você resolverá esse problema.