# Contornar imagem com texto em CSS

Tags: html, css, front-end, posicionamento, img

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site, mas sem utilizar qualquer *framework* para tal; quero destacar que apenas me iniciei nos estudos de *front*, e que CSS me é totalmente novo.

Eu estou tentando fixar uma imagem numa determinada região de uma div (isto esta ok) e alocar um texto ao seu redor. Todavia, não está funcionando como o desejado. Abaixo a imagem do que tenho até o momento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso é fazer com que o texto "flua" ao redor do personagem, mas não tenho ideia de como fazê-lo, e já quebrei bastante a cabeça com esse problema. Toda ajuda é bem vinda. Segue o código que eu estou usando tb:

HTML:

```
<section class="welcome">
    <h1>Seja o Melhor</h1>
    <img class="featured  put-on-top-left" src="img/teemo.png" alt="Conquiste a vitória!">
    <a class="featured-link" href="">Criar nova <em>build</em></a>
    <p class="get-around-right">Crie e compare estratégias de <em>build</em>, analisando as estátiscas que são modificadas a cada novo item escolhido e obtenha o melhor conjunto de itens para o seu campeão!</p>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    border: 5px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #e9eaec
}

.welcome h1 {
    font-family: 'roman-grids-cap';
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #4d4d4d
}

.featured {
    max-width: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 27px;
    left: 0px
}

.featured-link {
    display: block
}
```

Desde já, agradeço por toda e qqr ajuda!

Comment: tentou display block na imagem?

Comment: @LucasTorres isso não funciona, pois os limites de uma tag img são um tetraedro. O que o OP precisa é fazer com que os limites da imagem sejam um polígono com (bem mais do que) quatro lados.

Comment: Até onde eu sei ([link](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/03/27/freeing-the-floats-of-the-future-from-the-tyranny-of-the-rectangle/)), isto ainda não é uma possibilidade. Existem plugins que poderiam fazer isso, mas não funcionará em todos os browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente acredito que o que você quer não seja possível. Os limites dos elementos HTML são todos, por padrão, retângulos. Você pode até rotacioná-los de forma que se tornem losangos ou outras formas, mas no final das contas você ainda vai ter elementos com limites definidos por quatro lados. Perceba que isso ocorre porque o motor de HTML dos navegadores não leva em consideração coisas como a transparência das imagens.

Não é possível, apenas com *HTML*, *Javascript* e *CSS*, fazer com que o texto flua ao redor de uma imagem transparente. Você pode tentar duas alternativas:

- **Alternativa pontual:** você pode incluir o texto direto na imagem. A vantagem é que dessa forma você pode fazer algo realmente bonito e que terá a mesma apresentação em qualquer navegador. A desvantagem é que isso requer um trabalho específico para cada imagem diferente - não é possível reaproveitar a solução facilmente entre imagens distintas.
- **Alternativa McGyver:** você pode fazer a imagem flutuar sobre os demais componentes (i.e.: `position: absolute` (ou `fixed`)), e colocar várias *div*'s sem texto, mas com largura, atrás da imagem. Cada *div* teria um comprimento diferente de acordo com a sua necessidade. A vantagem é que não é necessário editar a imagem. Mas além da mesma desvantagem do método anterior, você precisará testar isso em cada navegador e potencialmente terá que desenvolver uma formatação para cada navegador diferente. **Disclaimer:** dado o tamanho da gambiarra, esta solução condena sua alma à uma eternidade de tormentos no inferno após a sua desencarnação.

**P.s.:**

> Eu estou desenvolvendo um site, mas sem utilizar qualquer framework para tal(...)

Você pode encarar o código como peças, e os *frameworks* como ferramentas. É completamente possível fixar um prego em uma parede ou um parafuso em uma tábua sem a utilização de martelos ou chaves de fenda, mas você irá se machucar. Bastante. E seus amigos questionarão sua sanidade. Com programação não é muito diferente.

Comment: Hey Renan, obrigado pela sua resposta! Ela realmente foi bastante elucidativa e didática! Bem, acho que vou pensar num outro _layout_, mais simples, para esta tarefa.

Ahh, em relação a não usar _frameworks_ é uma exigência de meu professor rs

Mas realmente, muito obrigado!

Comment: @D.Brai desejo sucesso no seu curso. Se você vai fazer isso para aprender, então é válido não usar frameworks, pois assim você vai aprender como os frameworks funcionam por dentro.

Answer (score 2):

Vou postar uma resposta mais atual, porém não é totalmente crossbrowser, não funciona no IE ou Edge, e só funciona na versão mais recente do FireFox (versão 62+)

A ideia aqui é usar a propriedade `shap-outside` com um `.png` de fundo transparente ou com um `clip-path` e usa-lo como "mascara" para flutuar o texto ao redor da imagem. Com isso vc consegue o efeito do texto contornando a imagem. No caso do `.png` é o canal `alpha` que vai fazer com que o texto contorne a imagem, e no caso do `clip-path` é o próprio `shap` construído que vai cuidar disso. Detalhe que vc pode precisar de `margins` ou `padding` para afastar o texto da imagem dando um respiro entre texto e imagem.

- Aqui vc pode consultar o suporte do seu browser para `shap-outside`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes
- Vc pode consultar o suporte do seu browser para `clip-path` aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

```css
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 400px;
}
.imagem {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: url(https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mario/images/0/0c/1000px-Mario_NSMB2.png/revision/latest?cb=20120920202215&path-prefix=pt-br);
    background-size: 80px 80px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: -15px
}
.star {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%); 
    shape-outside: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
    background-color: red;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.svgs {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
shape-outside: url(https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg);
background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img class="imagem" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mario/images/0/0c/1000px-Mario_NSMB2.png/revision/latest?cb=20120920202215&path-prefix=pt-br" alt="">
    <b>Usando .PNG</b>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita animi consequatur modi voluptates ea nobis veritatis accusantium vitae, earum officia?</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <b>Usando clip-path</b>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita animi consequatur modi voluptates ea nobis veritatis accusantium vitae, earum officia? </p>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img class="svgs" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg" alt="">
    <b>SVG não funciona no shap-outside</b>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita animi consequatur modi voluptates ea nobis veritatis accusantium vitae, earum officia? </p>
</div>
```

**OBS:** O efeito utilizando `.png` normalmente só funciona se a imagem estiver hospedada em algum servidor, mesmo que localmente. Então para testar em ambiente local sugiro que acesse os arquivos pelo `localhost` usando Wamp, Xamp, etc, ou que coloque no FTP de algum server.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca sua imagem em uma span ou div e o texto. Na imagem você coloca float: left.
Exemplo:

```html
<span>
    <img src="suaimagem.jpg" style="width:100px; height: 100px; float: left;">
    <h1>Olá Mundo!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.</p>
    </span>
```