# Texto contornando imagem/div redonda

Tags: html, css

Estou em dúvidas em como fazer o texto contornar a imagem/div redonda.

Segue o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Talvez poderíamos começar assim:

**html**

```
<div id="texto-esquerdo">
    <p> 
        Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos...
    </p>
</div>
<div id="circulo-foto" style="background-image: url('imagem');">
</div>
<div id="texto-direito">
    <p> 
        Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos...
    </p>
</div>
```

Utilizando uma div, e posteriormente colocando `border-radius` para ficar redonda. Mas como fazer o texto contornar a div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai precisar usar a propriedade `shape-outside` mas ela só funciona em alguns browsers como vc pode ver aqui:

https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside

Documentação **W3C**: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/

Veja um modelo funcionando. *(tem que abrir no Chrome ou Safari, pois tem que ser browser WebKit)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  shape-outside: ellipse(100px 200px at 50% 50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperiores. Consequuntur voluptates illo rerum recusandae pariatur asperiores, aspernatur, saepe ipsum error dolorem, quod inventore possimus modi deleniti tenetur et officiis. Nemo ab in totam ratione sequi error, ea dolorum repudiandae omnis, eaque facere impedit fugiat. Dolorum distinctio autem sequi enim quidem esse accusamus repudiandae voluptatum nobis, velit, molestiae. Eaque maiores, harum. Saepe esse repellendus sint. Labore provident optio quis commodi quod quaerat quo similique perspiciatis libero facere. Suscipit odit quas nemo, enim laudantium, provident repellendus natus nostrum facilis expedita adipisci qui, harum minus quidem officia cupiditate repellat ut praesentium. Possimus corporis, error atque ex adipisci, illum suscipit pariatur saepe impedit aliquam amet eos reiciendis quidem hic, nisi. Sint nobis modi, nesciunt quasi placeat quia. Veniam inventore corrupti quisquam illum debitis vitae accusamus nobis alias cum iste error magnam, cupiditate earum! Incidunt at consequuntur, rem ipsa odio ipsum deleniti repudiandae blanditiis harum ut in, fugit officia rerum ad, corporis dolore! Commodi repellendus esse quibusdam enim qui totam ipsum, consequuntur officia vel dolores, quod corrupti eveniet maiores minus explicabo, sapiente ratione doloribus laboriosam impedit nesciunt a obcaecati quam veritatis! Placeat, velit possimus delectus, atque voluptate iste alias illo, dolor odit ipsa facere quibusdam? Non omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores tempore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperiores. Consequuntur voluptates illo rerum recusandae pariatur asperiores, aspernatur, saepe ipsum error dolorem, quod inventore possimus modi deleniti tenetur et officiis. Nemo ab in totam ratione sequi error, ea dolorum repudiandae omnis, eaque facere impedit fugiat. Dolorum distinctio autem sequi enim quidem esse accusamus repudiandae voluptatum nobis, velit, molestiae. Eaque maiores, harum. Saepe esse repellendus sint. Labore provident optio quis commodi quod quaerat quo similique perspiciatis libero facere. Suscipit odit quas nemo, enim laudantium, provident repellendus natus nostrum facilis expedita adipisci qui, harum minus quidem officia cupiditate repellat ut praesentium. Possimus corporis, error atque ex adipisci, illum suscipit pariatur saepe impedit aliquam amet eos reiciendis quidem hic, nisi. Sint nobis modi, nesciunt quasi placeat quia. Veniam inventore corrupti quisquam illum debitis vitae accusamus nobis alias cum iste error magnam, cupiditate earum! Incidunt at consequuntur, rem ipsa odio ipsum deleniti repudiandae blanditiis harum ut in, fugit officia rerum ad, corporis dolore! Commodi repellendus esse quibusdam enim qui totam ipsum, consequuntur officia vel dolores, quod corrupti eveniet maiores minus explicabo, sapiente ratione doloribus laboriosam impedit nesciunt a obcaecati quam veritatis! Placeat, velit possimus delectus, atque voluptate iste alias illo, dolor odit ipsa facere quibusdam? Non omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores tempore</p>
```

Você também pode usar Polígonos para interagir com o texto:

```
.element{
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: shape-outside 1s;
}

.element:hover{
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Fonte e artigo em Ingles: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/
>
> Fonte e artigo em Ingles: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-exclusions-disambiguation
>
> Aqui tem um artigo em PT sobre `shape-outside` : https://tableless.com.br/css-shapes-e-text-wrap/

Comment: Você conhece um outro jeito que possui mais compatibilidade com outros browsers?

Comment: @Leonardo sim é possível fazer com um quadrado se te interessar. Mas com o texto seguindo o contorno de algum "shape" que não seja um quadrado ou retângulo não tem como até onde eu sei? **Se quiser da para fazer igual o texto que está entre aspas nessa imagem:** https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6b/fd/80/6bfd80fed11733d9a45f8c874232c23a.jpg